# Error when importing pyqtgraph jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, pyqtgraph

I get this error after running **import pyqtgraph as pg**

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-952aa750c92c> in <module>()
      6 import contextlib
      7
----> 8 import pyqtgraph as pg
      9 import pqtgraph.opengl as gl
     10

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\3dTracker\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\__init__.py in <module>()
     11 ## 'Qt' is a local module; it is intended mainly to cover up the differences
     12 ## between PyQt4 and PySide.
---> 13 from .Qt import QtGui
     14
     15 ## not really safe--If we accidentally create another QApplication, the process hangs (and it is very difficult to trace the cause)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\3dTracker\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\Qt.py in <module>()
    131 elif QT_LIB == PYQT4:
    132
--> 133     from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic
    134     try:
    135         from PyQt4 import QtSvg

ImportError: cannot import name 'QtGui'
```

---

Windows 10
Running in a jpyter notebook
3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:05:27) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

I have some code that uses pyqtgraph, today I realize that I am not able to run those programs. Before they were running perfectly. 
The only thing I remember changing in the environment is installing pandas.

I have tried reinstalling pyqtgraph and pyqt with no success

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyQtGraph automatically determines which Qt version is installed. By default it first looks for PyQt4, then for PySide and finally for PyQt5. Looking at your stack trace it seems that there is some old, broken PyQt4 installation which it tries to import without success.

You can force PyQtGraph to use PyQt5 by setting the `PYQTGRAPH_QT_LIB` environment variable to `PyQt5`. You probably need to restart your Jupyter after setting the environment variable.

Comment: You are completely right !!! Thank you very much!! To be more specific I solved the problem with the following lines                                                                                   >> import os
>> os.environ['PYQTGRAPH_QT_LIB'] = 'PyQt5'